# Variables and double quotes

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In this script I was just wondering why the double quotes are necessary around the variable $line

```
$cat script1
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<$1
exec 4<$2
exec 5>$3
while read line <&3
do
      echo "$line" >&5
done
while read line <&4
do 
      echo "$line" >&5
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around line if you don't want spaces (IFS characters, default spaces, tabs and newlines) to expand. Observe:

```
printf "a                   b\n" | 
while read line; do 
    echo $line
done
```

this will output:

```
a b
```

With qoutes:

```
printf "a                   b\n" | 
while read line; do 
    echo "$line"
done
```

will output:

```
a                   b
```

Quotes prohibit shell expansion. Grab a good [read on quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Also read about [IFS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) and be aware of `read` delimiter `-d` option and `-r` option.

If you whish to read from file, preserving leading and trailing whitespaces and the whole line, see [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and use:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Also note that using `while read` loops to parse files is *very* slow on bash. Try to use bash commands and moreutils and standard unix commands to parse files. If you really need to parse file line by line, [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and `parallel` are good programs for that. The script you presented may be just substituted by `cat "$1" "$2" >"$5"` (or more like `cat "$1" "$2" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' > "$5"`,  because leading and trailing whilespaces will not be preserved).

Also quote your variables. The `exec 3<$1` will fail if someone cals your function with file with spaces in the name, like: `./script1 "filename with spaces.txt"`. Use `exec 3<"$1"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, showing the differences, and the tip. I will make sure to quote my variables.